# How to make two lines of text aligned in the middle of the right side of an image?

Tags: html, css

guys. I'm trying to achive this with `img` and two `p`:
[image]
but what I get is this:
[image]

What am I doing wrong on the code below? Please help me!

HTML:

```
<div class="content-5">
     <img src="imagens/joao.png">
     <p class="nome">JOÃO SILVA</p>
     <p class="casamento">Fotógrafo de casamento</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.content-5 img {
vertical-align: middle;
display:inline;
margin-left:200px;
}
.nome {
    display:inline-block;
    font-family: "PFAgoraSansPro-Thin";
    font-size:22px;
    color:black;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-left:30px;
}
.casamento {
    display:inline;
    font-family: "open sans";
    font-size:16px;
    color:black;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <style>
        .content-5 img {
            vertical-align: middle;
            display:inline;
            margin-left:200px;
        }
        .nome {
            display:inline-block;
            font-family: "PFAgoraSansPro-Thin";
            font-size:22px;
            color:black;
            font-weight:bold;
            padding-left:30px;
        }
        .casamento {
            display:block;
            font-family: "open sans";
            font-size:16px;
            color:black;
            font-weight:normal;
        }
        </style>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>
        <div class="content-5">
             <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051_400x400.gif">
             <p class="nome">JOÃO SILVA</p>
             <p class="casamento">Fotógrafo de casamento</p>
        </div>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: @PedroHenriqueQuiste Did you copy my code and run it? That's working on my end using Google Chrome

Comment: Yes, but I didn't use the "style" tag. Copied it on the css doc, is there any problem?

Comment: .casamento {
            display:block;
            font-family: "open sans";
            font-size:16px;
            color:black;
            font-weight:normal;
        }

Did you change the display to block?

Comment: I copied the exact code into my editor, but it didn't work. I really don't know what is happening...

Comment: Which browser are you using? I tried that in Chrome and Edge and is working? When you say its not working, did you mean the work you are doing or my code?

Answer (score 0):

It's my modified list:

- use new margin and padding value in `.content-5 img` and `.nome`
- use `Flexbox` layout in `.content-5`
- add `.text-wrapper` to auto grow or shrink flexible items

https://jsfiddle.net/Lgqjd63u/

```css
.content-5 img {
  // margin-left: 200px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.nome {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "PFAgoraSansPro-Thin";
  font-size: 22px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  // padding-left:30px;
}

.casamento {
  font-family: "open sans";
  font-size: 16px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: normal;
}

/* new css */
.content-5 {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.text-wrapper p {
    margin: 0;
}
.text-wrapper {
    margin-left: 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-5">
  <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/604644048/sign051_400x400.gif">
  <div class="text-wrapper">
  <p class="nome">JOÃO SILVA</p>
  <p class="casamento">Fotógrafo de casamento</p>
  </div>  
</div>
```